# Why my jquery validator doesn't show up any alert msg?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I created a form with jquery validator attached to it. You can see it here http://jsfiddle.net/5WMff/1327/

however, when I fill all the data and hit send button - my page reloads and nothing from the php script (that contains for now only `echo "hey!!"` message) gets displayed on screen.
I believe there might be some problem in my syntax, but I don't see anything wrong in developer console in chrome..
Can you verify my fiddle and check whether those parts are correct:

```
p.name = "p";
p.type = "hidden";
p.value = hex_sha512($("#password").val());

// Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent. 
$("#password").val() = "";
```

and later on:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'includes/register.inc.php',
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    username: username,
    email: email,
    p : p,
    company: company,
    contact: contact,
    phone: phone,
    address1: address1,
    address2: address2,
    city: city,
    zipcode: zipcode,
    state: state,
    country: country

  },
  dataType: 'text',
  success: function(response) {
    alert('success');   
  },
  error: function(response){
    alert('ERROR');
  }
});
```

Comment: `$("#password").val() = "";`  <-- WRONG, that is not how jQuery works

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, how can I fix that?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: `$("#password").val("");` also this line: `p.value = hex_sha512($("#password").val());` hex_sha512 is not defined

Comment: Please never use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag unless your question is about the jQuery Validate plugin.   I also see no reason to tag this with PHP.

Answer (score 2):

I guess instead of `p` the html element you would have to send the value of it:

```
p : p.value,
```

and you have to reset the password element like:

```
$("#password").val('');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to stringify your data

```
JSON.stringify( data: {
username: username,
email: email,
p : p,
company: company,
contact: contact,
phone: phone,
address1: address1,
address2: address2,
city: city,
zipcode: zipcode,
state: state,
country: country});
```

Comment: Whoever did not like the answer.. Please mention in the comment so it should be useful in future reference

Comment: It is wrong, that is why. You are welcome. First you have the `data` inside the stringify which is wrong. Second it makes no sense why you would use JSON.Stringify when it should be reduced to a querystring name/value pairs.